# Rails nested has_many with additional context

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

I'm trying to describe the idea that a group of software services share similar dependencies but not all of the services are on the same version of a given dependency.

Consider the following models:

```
class Service < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :service_dependencies
  has_many :dependencies, through: :service_dependencies
end

class ServiceDependency < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :service
  belongs_to :dependency
end

class Dependency < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :service_dependencies
  has_many :services, through: :service_dependencies
  has_many :versions, foreign_key: 'dependency_id', class_name: 'DependencyVersion'
end

class DependencyVersion < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :dependency
end
```

While a `service` can have many `dependencies` and a given dependency can have many `versions` any service uses a single version of a dependency at a time.

How can I express that relationship so that I can establish what version of a dependency a service is currently using?

I considered that I could store the current version on the `service_dependencies` table but that feels like the wrong solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would add something like a

```
class Configuration < AR
  belongs_to :service
  belongs_to :dependency
  belongs_to :dependency_version
end
```

Yes, you would be  duplicating information, but it seems like that would be meaningful.  An instantiation of possibilities.